# Unable to read data from JTable editable cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am directly inserting data into JTable, suppose there are 5 rows in JTable and I inserted values in all and in last I am inserting value in a cell of fifth row, and cell is in editable mode, in this situation I cant read data from that cell.

Comment: You should add some code so we can know what you're trying to do...

Comment: Are you talking from program perspective or user perspective? Just remember - you have to leave cell as user in GUI to be able to read it from program side. Just click somewhere outside the last cell and editing will be done and program can read the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you set or get value from a cell in `JTable` you have to cancel/stop the editing.You can do this by

Assume `jTable1` is the varaible name of the `JTable`

```
/**
 * Tells the editor to stop editing and accept any partially edited
 * value as the value of the editor.  The editor returns false if
 * editing was not stopped; this is useful for editors that validate
 * and can not accept invalid entries.
 *
 * @return  true if editing was stopped; false otherwise
 */

 jTable1.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
```

or

```
/**
 * Tells the editor to cancel editing and not accept any partially
 * edited value.
 */
jTable1.getCellEditor().cancelCellEditing();
```